# Android Studio Facebook login error "ProxyAuthAppLoginStartQuery":

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, authentication

I implemented the Facebook api to my app and its working, but when I tested the app in another phone, It threw this error:

```
 Error performing query. [extra]: Errors while executing operation "ProxyAuthAppLoginStartQuery": At Query.proxy_auth_app_login_start: Failed to resolve field.
```

and when I click in the highlighted error, this piece is causing the error:

```
   mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

I don`t know what it is or what is causing this error :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure that the user on the other phone is listed as a developer / admin on the Facebook developer site under the roles menu.[image]

Comment: i try every method in the entire stackoveflow nothing is working

Answer (score 20):

**Method 1:** App under *Development / Testing* mode

1. Select your App on Facebook Developer [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).
2. Go to Roles > Roles , and add the Facebook account that you want to test with.

**Method 2:** App under *Deployment* mode

1. Select your App on Facebook Developer [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).
2. Go to App Review > Make "Your App Name" application public? > Switch to Yes.