# Facebook Authentication Not Working with Firebase UI in Android

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have used Firebase UI to implement authentication in a couple of projects before, however, for some reason, I cannot get Facebook authentication to work in this current project. Each time the Sign in with Facebook button is clicked, it initiates what appears to be an authentication flow and then comes back to the Auth UI screen without doing anything.

No account is created in Firebase console and nothing is logged on Facebook. Here are the steps that I have taken and double checked.

1. Added Firebase UI latest library to project - 2.2.0
2. Add Facebook Android SDK
3. Updated other Firebase libraries to 11.4.0
4. Ensured Google Play services is 3.0.0
5. Ensured Facebook authentication is enabled in Firebase console
6. Ensured Facebook App ID and App Secret is added to Firebase console
7. Ensure Firebase oAuth redirect is added to Facebook
8. Ensure App is added correctly to Facebook and enabled
9. Ensure Facebook App Id is added to res/string resource file
10. Used a different Facebook account that is different from my
    developer account
11. Tried on two different physical devices

There is no error message, no Log cat, what else could I be missing? Any help will be appreciated Here is my AuthUiActivity

https://gist.github.com/valokafor/d4d5663bcdcf999be1cd41f331a3b883

And here is my Gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') {
        // Necessary to avoid version conflicts
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }


    compile('org.mnode.ical4j:ical4j:1.0.6') {
        exclude group: 'commons.io'
    }


    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }


    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'be.billington.calendar.recurrencepicker:library:1.1.1'
    compile 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:3.2.7.Final'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-camera:0.4.4'
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.5'
    compile 'com.github.fiskurgit:ChipCloud:3.0.3'
    compile 'com.github.adroitandroid:ChipCloud:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Firebase Auth Console
[image: Firebase Console Showing Auth Tab]

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, it was a very simple thing.

The Facebook id should be added to the string like this:

```
<string name="facebook_application_id" translatable="false">98765xxxxxxx</string>
```

instead of the way appears in the Firebase UI doc like this

```
  <string name="facebook_app_id" translatable="false">987565xxxxxx</string>
```

Once I made that update, thanks to this question [FirebaseUI Authentication with Facebook not logging in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519255/firebaseui-authentication-with-facebook-not-logging-in?rq=1) the issue was resolved